# Spring Load database properties

Tags: spring

I would like to load database values in runtime, when spring application launch.

```
public List<MyBean> beanValues() {
 List<MyBean> value; // fetch all values from database
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use spring bean. So that data will be loaded when application launch up

```
@Configuration
class BeanList {
@Bean
  public List<MyBean> beanValues() {
      /*
           List<MyBean> result = dao.getAllBeans(); // use your dao to fetch all 
           
           // values from database and store it in a variable
      */
  }
}
// now to access the values use Autowired annotation
@Component
class MyApp {
   
@Autowired
private List<MyBean> beanValues;

}
```